# How to correctly push changes to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

Currently whenever I make a change to some code I do the following in terminal:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Some changes"
git push heroku master
```

I am not 100% certain, but this seems like it is redeploying the entire project and installing all packages again. If this is the case is there a way to only push the changes made?

For example, if I change one line of code, I just want to push that one file with the change, not the entire project again.

Comment: `git init` initialize the repository. You have to do it only once. The rest is okay. The correct way is to work on local enviroment and push changes to the server/repo when a feature is complete.

Comment: Yes, I am working on local environment but sometimes I just have to make a minor change and was just wondering if there wasn't a way to just push that one file in the way you would use ftp to upload some_page.php where you made one line change for example

Comment: When you `push` you are sending the changes of the repo. No need to specify which file changes or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you're packaging the app, e.g. with `webpack.config`. Typically you'd package and deploy the entire project to the server each time. This is the correct way to do it (rather than just trying to replace one file), so that you can do project-wide actions like minifying code, processing your CSS, etc. The server would not download/install external packages that are already there unless you specify a different version in your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

git init only be oncethen every time you make a change just run

git add. (add all changes)

git commit -m "commit"

git push origin master

Comment: What is the difference between push origin master and push heroku master?

Comment: `origin master` is typically your github repository and `heroku master` is obviously the hosted repository. I always run `git push origin master` to move my stuff to github and then `git push heroku master`

Comment: origin works for other code repositories
in your case it would be heroku master

Answer (score 1):

It's because react has to do some of its magic before Heroku can deploy it properly.  That magic includes installing the node modules, compiling all the source files, and then optimizing everything before outputting the build folder with everything in it.  There's not a 1:1 relationship between the one line in one file you changed and the build output - react requires a re-build.